# DateTime format culture - how to change it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

With this line in my `web.config`, numbers like `2.44` or `0.5` works properly - generally all decimals in `ViewModels`.
 I found solution here, that if I want to have decimals in viewmodel, I have to change `globalization` like this:

```
<globalization culture="en-us" uiCulture="pl-PL" />
```

But now date is in format `6/19/2013 10:04:18 PM` - I want european format, like `19-6-2013 22:04:18`. Always and automatically.

When I change `culture` into `pl-PL`, date format is proper, but decimals in textboxes doesn't work.. (return 0 when number is decimal).

How can I have european datetime format and working decimals?

Regards

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have an inherent format. You can pass in the wanted culture when you `ToString` it.

Comment: Do I have to change all of my `DateTime` variables into specyfic culture with `ToString`? This is not a solution.

Comment: Well then maybe you can create your own custom Culture info and then set up the separators as you need and assign that as your current culture

Comment: ok, but in my project I use many times code like this one - `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.createDate)`. And now, do I have to change it all? Here is answer, why I had to use `culture="en-us"` -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657795/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-binded-decimal-empty-when-using-floating-point-numbers

Comment: It is not clear what your actual issue _is_. You are either using `pl-PL` or `en-US` for parsing strings as dates. You can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

I had quite the same problem, as I'm from Romania. Here's my solution:

**Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Date.cshtml** (create folders and file if not existing)

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

@{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (Model != null) {
        dt = (System.DateTime)Model;
    }
    @dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Basically, whenever you're using Html.Display or Html.DisplayFor for a DateTime (nullable, in my example), it will be rendered according to this template. You can also set up an editor template (where I use jquery ui's DatePicker). You can read more about MVC templates [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)

**Script referenced in Layout.cs (therefore available in all views)**

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    value = floatValue(value);
    return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(value);
}
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    value = floatValue(value);
    return this.optional(element) ||
        (value >= param[0] && value <= param[1]);
}

function floatValue(value) {
    return parseFloat(value.replace(",", "."));
}
```

This is for fixing the decimal mark issue in textboxes and such.

I'm not saying it's the best solution (at least the latter part, where actually replacing dots and commas might appear raw), but it gets the job done. I also mention that I use

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="ro" uiCulture="ro" />
```

, thereby forcing the culture (I never have to display date or currency - or whatever decimal number - in a different format).